# Rotate image in JQuery

Tags: jquery, rotation, jquery-animate, flip, image-rotation

I have created an accordian menu in Jquery using the following...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(
                function()
                {
                    $('#menu_list .menu_head').click(
                        function(e)
                        {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $(this).closest('li').find('.menu_content').not(':animated').slideToggle();

                        }
                    )
                }
            );
        </script>
```

However, I would like to add another event handler to the 'click' function so that an imaged nested inside the .menu_head class rotates 90 degrees on click (so moves from pointing right to pointing down when the menu expands).

I have tried adding the following line:

```
$(this).find('img').rotate({animateTo:90});
```

but still, no joy.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Comment: I think it would be helpful if we had the HTML too.

Comment: Hi Danny, it is actually for my site that is already live; www.gfloor.co.uk :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using CSS transitions. Here's an example:

```
.menu_head img{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
```

Then use:

```
$(this).find('img').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
```

The CSS code tells the browser to animate the 'transform' property when it's changed and that the transition time should be 0.5s.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/pTQ5g/1/

**Update:** To get it working with `toggleClass()` just create a class like this:

```
.menu_head img.rotate90{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Then use:

```
$(this).find('img').toggleClass('rotate90');
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pTQ5g/3/

Comment: Hi Joe, This is a great answer, thank you. However I would like the image to rotate back to it's original state when it is clicked again. To show you what I am trying to achieve, please check out www.gfloor.co.uk - This is the site I am working on and I would like the arrows to rotate in harmony with the accordian menu displaying/hiding i.e. rotate 90 degrees on display, go back to it's default position when the menu is closed.

Comment: I am trying to use the .toggleClass() method to switch .menu_arrow (default) to .menu_arrow_rotated (90degree rotation) but with no joy.  Is it possible to achieve it this way?

Comment: @tom1bomb - I see what you mean, I've just updated my answer with a solution - hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Joe, tried to vote you up but still a noob :) Much appreciated!!